# django-zinnia integration with existing django website - permissions, model access etc

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I have built a django website, which requires blog functionality. Rather than roll my own, I have decided to use [django-zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia), to provide blog functionality for my site.

I have managed to change the template to integrate more closely, with the pages on my existing site -  however, there are still things I haven't managed yet - to do.

I have come come across [zinnia template tags](https://django-blog-zinnia.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9/templatetags.html), but they are not giving me the full level of access that I need.

Specifically, I need to do the following:

1. Access to properties of post (i.e. "entries" in Zinnia lingo) and comments so that I can display the following items on my home page:

   - Show thumbnails of last N posts (or most popular posts for example)
   - Show last X comments
2. Programatically create new posts - and specify the state of the post, i.e. draft/published
3. Restrict viewing certain posts to authenticated users belonging to a specific django user group.

Am I able to get this tight integration between Zinnia and my django website - or am I better of writing my own blog app, with the requested features?